# Rails precompile constant uninitialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, initialization, asset-pipeline, assets

I wanted to preload the configuration (from ".yml" files). In one of my initializer files (config/initializers/facebook.rb) I have following line of code:

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[Rails.env]
```

So, it works like a charm in the "DEVELOPMENT" mode. Once I switch to the production mode, it keeps telling me, that FACEBOOK_CONFIG is an uninitialized constant for my "`facebook.js.coffee.erb`" file, located in **assets/javascript** (If it matters), if I want to o "rake assets:precompile". I've tried doing random stuff, like: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` or

> rake assets:precompile:all

, but no luck

I have tried assigning "`initialize_on_precompile = true`" variable for my production environment (although, it should be true by default), just in case.

Why it doesn't work in production mode (But, I want to emphasise, that it does work(!) in the development environment).

Can someone help with that one ?

Comment: what does your yml file look like (minus your credentials of course) and are you booting in production mode locally or is this failing on a service like heroku?

Comment: Can you try raising an exception on the initializer file and see if it gets triggered? Another thing to try is, raise an exception on the initializer file and run a different rake task that also loads the Rails environment. Try both on development and production environment (RAILS_ENV=production)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered exactly the same problem. This is because your javascript(coffescript) file makes reference to a constant that is defined in an initializer. Because it is precompiled before the initializer the app throws an error.

This is the simple solution I found. You place this code at the bottom of your application.rb file in config:

```
module AssetsInitializers
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "assets_initializers.initialize_rails",
                :group => :assets do |app|
      require "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/facebook.rb" 
    end
  end
end
```

It manually loads up certain files from the initializer folder. It solved my problem.

Hopefully this was the issue for you as well.

Comment: Not sure if the OP is still monitoring this question - but I'd actually be surprised if this didn't solve the prob. I'm just foaming at the mouth for  +50 points over here.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Rails

  class << self
    def facebook_config
      @@facebook_config ||= nil
    end

    def facebook_config=(facebook_config)
      @@facebook_config = facebook_config
    end
  end
end

Rails.facebook_config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[Rails.env]

# And you can use it like this in anywhere:
puts Rails.facebook_config
```